# Obtaining distance from Google Maps API and storing it in a global variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, global-variables

I would like to assign distance value, which is computed in the function block to a global variable. I am using google maps API, the directions service is able to compute the distance, but my global variable "distance" is returning undefined. I want the distance computed in the calculateRoute function to be assigned to global variable "distance". Kindly assist!

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /**Global distance variable**/
        var distance;

        //Default start point in any given route
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.1687096773592578, 36.82577480866917);

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        function init() {

            //route_data is coming from DB
          var distance_data = route_data.length;
            do {
                //Check whether request exists in a given route                
                
                    waypointsArray.push({
                        location: new google.maps
                            .LatLng(parseFloat(
                                    route_data[w]['latitude']),
                                parseFloat(
                                    route_data[w]['longitude'])
                            ),
                        stopover: true
                    });                

                distance_data--;

            } while (distance_data != 0 && current_route == previous_route && current_route != '')

calculateRoute();

window.alert(distance);

            //function to compute total route
            function calculateRoute() {

                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: finish,
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                };

                //Google maps directions service API
                directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {                        

                        var route = response.routes[0];
                        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                        //summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";                       
                        for (var k = 0; k < route.legs.length; k++) {
                            var routeSegment = k + 1;
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[k].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
                            distance += route.legs[k].distance.text;

                        }
                        computeTotalDistance(response);                        
                    } else {
                        alert("directions response " + status);
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: where is it "returning undefined" ... it won't have a value until after the asynchronous code in the `directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {` callback is complete - but your code never accesses that variable anywhere else - your code never calls `calculateRoute` anyway! and what does `computeTotalDistance` do with `response`?

Comment: your do/while loop makes no sense, since you don't initialise `distance_data` but in the do/while loop you `distance_data--;` - you also reference `previous_route` and  `current_route` - in that loop - what are they? They don't change in that loop, so how can that condition ever change! seriously, there's a LOT wrong with the code - it'll never do anything

Comment: Where do you call calculate route?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Here is the function call:

Comment: right ...a) you're alerting a variable that doesn't exist, and b) due to asynchrony, you're attempting to alert before the value is calculated c) you still have MANY more issues to solve - like, what is current_route, what is previous_route, decrementing distance_data results in distance_data being NAN ... and that's just a couple of things from my first two comments you haven't addresses in your code

Comment: @JaromandaX This is just a code snippet. I have defined all the variables in my main code.

Comment: so, how do current_route and previous_route change in the do/while loop? they have to change, otherwise there's no point in testing their condition if it's always the same. Also, how is distance_data anything but undefined and then NaN ... your unseen "main code" can't inject useful values for you while the code you've shown is running - see, if your code was close to "functional", I'd have an answer for you, but, I can't with what you've posted

Comment: @JaromandaX How can I retrieve the distance value once it's calculated. I really appreciate your assistance on this.

Comment: make `calculateRoute` return a Promise that resolves with the value you need ... then you can use async/await or promise.then to access this asynchronously generated value

Comment: @JaromandaX Can you share an example on how to do this. I haven't a clue on how to do that.

Comment: @peytlucas posted an answer

Comment: The distance calculation should probably use `route.legs[k].distance.value` rather than `route.legs[k].distance.text` as the latter includes useless text data such as `km`...

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, let me try the solution you shared. However, I needed to assign distance to GLOBAL variable since I needed to use the distance value for computations in some other parts of the code. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, but you still need to know WHEN the value is available - asynchrony is like that ... let me make a little change

Comment: actually, no ... there's no way to have access to `distance` globally, since `init` is called asynchronously, and within that function, `distance` is calculated asynchronously - you could make it so `distance` is reliably accessible within `init` ... but, outside of `init`, since it is, I assume, executed when google maps API loads, there's no reliable way to access `distance` outside of the `init` function - asynchrony strikes again

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you handle asynchrony with a Promise

Note: no GLOBAL variable for the distance are required in this example - because you shouldn't use global variables for asynchronous results

```
//Default start point in any given route
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-1.1687096773592578, 36.82577480866917);

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

function init() {

    //route_data is coming from DB
    var distance_data = route_data.length;
    do {
        //Check whether request exists in a given route

        waypointsArray.push({
            location: new google.maps
            .LatLng(parseFloat(
                    route_data[w]['latitude']),
                parseFloat(
                    route_data[w]['longitude'])),
            stopover: true
        });

        distance_data--;

    } while (distance_data != 0 && current_route == previous_route && current_route != '')

    calculateRoute()
    .then(distance => window.alert(distance))
    .catch(status => alert("directions response " + status));

    //function to compute total route
    function calculateRoute() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // createa promise
            var distance = 0;
            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: finish,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            //Google maps directions service API
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                    var route = response.routes[0];
                    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                    //summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                    for (var k = 0; k < route.legs.length; k++) {
                        var routeSegment = k + 1;
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[k].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
                        distance += route.legs[k].distance.text;

                    }
                    computeTotalDistance(response);
                    resolve(distance); // resolve with a distance
                } else {

                    reject(status); // reject if there's a problem
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment above - rather than using the `text` property from each of the route legs you should use the `value` as that is a valid number rather than a string. The `Promise` allows you to proceed with the processing of the results in a non-linear manner as is the nature of asynchronous functions. A similar result can be obtained using `async` and `await`

For the example here I selected two random locations for calculating the route rather than the original code which draws content from your db - however it should though serve OK to illustrate.

```
let distance=0;


function initMap(){
    const options={
        center:new google.maps.LatLng( -1.1687096773592578, 36.82577480866917 ),
        mapTypeId:'satellite',
        zoom: 16
    };
    const route={// random locations picked for purpose of example only
        start:new google.maps.LatLng(-1.1687096773592578, 36.82577480866917),
        finish:new google.maps.LatLng(-1.472426, 36.956011)
    };
    const map=new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), options );
    const oDir=new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const oRender=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    
    oRender.setMap( map );
    oRender.setPanel( document.getElementById('dir') )
    
    
    const calculate=()=>new Promise(( resolve, reject )=>{
        let oReq={
            origin:route.start,
            destination:route.finish,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        oDir.route( oReq, ( response, status )=>{
            if( status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK ){
                oRender.setDirections( response );
                let res=response.routes[0];
                for( let k=0; k < res.legs.length; k++ ) {
                    distance+=Number( res.legs[k].distance.value );
                }
                resolve(distance)
            }
            reject(status)
        });             
    });
    
    
    const formatresult=(n)=>[
        'The distance is:',
        n+'m',
        (n/1000)+'Km'
    ].join( String.fromCharCode(10) );
    

    // the distance is calculated within the `calculate` function and passed back
    // (resolved) by the Promise. The `Promise Chain` continues with `then`
    // and the final output is formatted ( an alert )
    calculate()
        .then( res=>alert( formatresult( res ) ) )
        .catch( err=>alert( err ) )
}
```

[Proof of concept](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/50txkh8u/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Professor Abronsius & Jaromanda X ! Let me try your method in as much as what I wanted was to assign the distance value to a GLOBAL variable. I think maybe based on my special case, I may have to execute the code I want to compute within the asynchronous function. Thanks again!